# what can be the reason for Null Pointer Exception in this snippet of code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting null-exception throw error in the following code. What can be the reason for it?

```
 public static String[] CreateVocab(BufferedReader buffR) throws IOException{
    String[] arr = null;
    int i = 0;
    arr[i]= null;
    String line = new String();
    while((line = buffR.readLine()) != null){
        arr[i] = line;
        i=i+1;
    }
    return arr;     
}
```

Compiler is showing Null ponter exception in  the code 
 `arr[i]=null`.

Comment: I see NO reason to downvote this question. And no reason for closeing too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created the array - and an array won't solve your problem anyway, because it can't resize. We don't know the number of lines in advance.

Use a collection instead:

```
public static String[] CreateVocab(BufferedReader buffR) throws IOException{
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while((line = buffR.readLine()) != null){
        lines.add(line);
    }
    return lines.toArray(new String[]{});     
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the cause:

```
String[] arr = null;
int i = 0;
arr[i]= null; // 'arr' is null
```

As the number of lines being read is unknown suggest using an `ArrayList<String>` to store the lines read, and the use `ArrayList.toArray()` to return a `String[]` (if returning an `ArrayList<String>` is not acceptable).

Example that returns a `List<String>`:

```
public static List<String> CreateVocab(BufferedReader buffR)
    throws IOException
{
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while((line = buffR.readLine()) != null){
        arr.add(line);
    }
    return arr;     
}
```

To return an array change `return` to:

```
return arr.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arr = null; //here you are setting arr to null
int i = 0;
arr[i]= null;        // here you are trying to reference arr
```